# Ubuntu 12.10 doesn't boot, HP DV4

Tags: installation

I installed the latest version of Ubuntu without Windows 7 (I erased the partition and installed ubuntu on it). After I installed ubuntu, I restarted my computer and then it couldn't start. it gets stuck in the HP logo and I can't do anything else, what can a do?

Answer (score 0):

Try a new download (bittorrent is more reliable) and installation (USB is less prone to scratches).

See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131879/corrupted-file-ubuntu-os-download-11-10-12-4).